# Issue with referncing objects that do not have a name

Tags: java, arraylist

I´m new to programming and I have this task to implement a simple booking System for bus tickets.

We´re supposed to implement a method that adds new bus routes using the attributes: `busNumber`, `start`, `destination`, `price`, `currency`. To save the bus routes I´m using an arraylist and save new objects like this:

```
Booking.add(new Booking(1, "France", "Latvia", 2.05, Currency.EUR))
```

My issue now is working with those objects since they don´t have a name. I don't know the exact number of objects, so I have to do it this way (i think so at least). Where the issue occurred is at the method "remove", that is supposed to remove a bus route. I thought I could use an Iterator to iterate through the ArrayList and compare the `busNumber`s but it´s not working.

Another issue I have is, that when I want to print all the objects in my Array list it just prints the last object as many times as there are objects in my ArrayList. Also, my method and attributes are all static now otherwise I wouldn´t know how to use them in another class.

Does anybody has some advice for a newbie please?

My Code is below:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Booking {

static int busNumber;
static int customerID = 1; //First customerID starts with 1
static String name;
static double price;
static int invoiceNumber = 1; //First invoicenumber starts with 1.
static String start;
static String destination;
static Currency currency;

static ArrayList<Booking> bookable = new ArrayList<Booking>();

//Constructor
public Booking(int busNumber, String start, String destination, double price, Currency currency) {
  this.busNumber = busNumber;
  this.start = start;
  this.destination = destination;
  this.price = price;
  this.currency = currency;

 }

public int getBusNumber() {
  return busNumber;
}

public static void add(Booking add) { // add-method. Adds the bus routes to the booking system
  bookable.add(add);
}

public static void remove(int busNumber) { // Here´s one of my issues. That´s what i have.
  Iterator<Booking> it = bookable.iterator();

  if ( == busNumber) {
bookable.remove(it);
  }
}

public static void listRoute() {
  for (Booking element : bookable) {
Terminal.printLine(toString(element));
  }
}

public static String toString(Booking element) {
  return "000" + busNumber + " " + start + " " + destination + " " + price + " " + currency;
}
}

My second class which is later supposed to be the UI:

public class Input {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Booking.add(new Booking(1, "Mannheim", "Karlsruhe", 2.05, Currency.EUR));
  Booking.add(new Booking(2, "Heidelberg", "Karlsruhe", 3.05, Currency.JPY));
  Booking.add(new Booking(3, "Germersheim", "Karlsruhe", 4.05, Currency.USD));
  Booking.listRoute();
 }
}
```

The Output is: "0003, "Germersheim", "Karlsruhe", 4.05, Currency.USD" 3 times..

Comment: Since all your methods are static, they are shared between all instances of the class. You need to make them non static and move the ArrayList out of the class.

Comment: compiler-errors, please resolve the compiler issues first. also, every attribute is static, which is causing this issue. values are getting overwritten by the last object set in the list